# Spectral gaps of common graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, mixing

I'm looking for the spectral gap of common graphs (alternatively, the mixing time of a (lazy) random walk on these graphs). Asymptotic values are fine. Assume that every node has a sufficient number of self-loops. (For regular graphs at least d many)
Spectral gaps should be for example,

- Clique $O(1)$
- Star $O(1)$
- Expanders $O(1)$
- Binary tree $\Theta(1/n)$
- Cycle $\Theta(1/n^2)$
- Grid $\Theta(1/n)$

What about other classes?
For example d-nary trees or graphs arising from preferential attachment (I believe these should have $O(1)$).
I'm especially interested in graphs where the gap between conductance and spectral gap is very high (Does this happen when the degree is small?).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice table in [Aldous & Fill](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/RWG/book.pdf) page 169 including many quantities of interest. Most notably the relaxation time $\tau_2$, which is defined as the inverse of the spectral gap.